# How can I export the data from a LibreOffice Writer graph to e.g. Calc?

Tags: linux, libreoffice, spreadsheet, graph

I have a LibreOffice Writer document (.odt; originally .docx) with a simple 2D graph containing one line.  If I right-click on the graph and choose Edit, then right-click again and select Data Table, I get the data in a nice 2D table for me to edit.  However, I would like to export/copy these data to e.g. LibreOffice Calc (or e.g. a .csv file).  I can copy the whole graph to Calc, but run into the same issue there (i.e., I can edit but not copy the data).  Is there a way to do this?  It is a long data series, so typing down everything elsewhere is no option.  I'm on a Linux platform.

Comment: When you say "but run into the same issue there" I'm not clear what issue you mean.

Comment: That there too I can edit, but not copy the data - I added this to the question.